# How can I write this C code in Rubymotion?

Tags: ios, c, rubymotion

I'm working through some of the code examples in [Learning Core Audio: A Hands-on Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0321636848/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=0321636848&linkCode=as2&tag=gavimorrhome-21)

Although I've worked previously with Objective-C, I'm working on a Rubymotion app at the moment and I'd like to be able to transpose the code in the book to Rubymotion for my app.

There are a few C functions and idioms that I'm not sure about though. Can anybody tell me IF and HOW I can re-write the following in RM?

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
memset(&asbd, 0, sizeof(asbd));
```

I've got as far as identifying that asbd is a Pointer. So:

```
asbd = Pointer.new(AudioStreamBasicDescription.type)
```

But both the `sizeof()` and `memset()` functions cough up **NoMethodErrors**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asbd` is not a pointer, but a structure.  In RubyMotion that is represented by a class.  The `memset` is just initializing the memory of the structure to all zeros.  I'm not sure if RubyMotion sets the fields to zero by default, so you could initialize each field manually like so (which is certainly more clear if a bit wordy):

```
asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription.new

asbd.mSampleRate = 0.0
asbd.mFormatID = 0
asbd.mFormatFlags = 0
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 0
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 0
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 0
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 0
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 0
asbd.mReserved = 0
```

If you need a pointer to `asbd`, I believe you do this:

```
asbd_ptr = Pointer.new(AudioStreamBasicDescription.type)
asbd_ptr[0] = asbd
```

So if wanted to pass `&asbd`, you would pass `asbd_ptr` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In the C example, a pointer to the struct is what's being passed in to the memset() function. How would one create a pointer to a struct like this in RM? (Although I accept that I don't need to in this case)